# If $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{1271}$ is defined by $f(x)=[943][x]$, then $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. Is $f$ also surjective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

Consider the function $f:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{1271}$ defined by $f(x)=[943][x]$.

a) Prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all integers $x$ and $y$.

b) Prove or disprove: $f$ is surjective.

For part a), I got

$[943][x+y]=[943x]+[943y]=f(x)+f(y)$

and for part b)

$\gcd(943,1271)=41$

$41\mid 943x$, so for every $f(x) \in \mathbb Z_{1271}$, there exists an $x \in \mathbb Z$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks a ton!

Comment: $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your work: we have that

$$\text{gcd}(1271,943)=41\;\implies\;\exists\;x,y,\in\Bbb Z\;\;\text{such that}\;\;1271x+943y=41$$

but then, for example, there can't be $\;m\in\Bbb Z\;$ with $\;943m=1\pmod{1271}\;$ , otherwise

$$943m=1\pmod{1271}\implies 943=1+1271k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies 1=943-1271k$$

and since $\;41\;$ divides the right side we get that also $\;41\mid1\;$ , which is absurd. So the function isn't surjective.